# Spark java filter isin method or something else?

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I have around 2 billions of rows in my cassandra database which I filter with the isin method based on an experimentlist with 4827 Strings, as shown below. However, I noticed that after the distinct command I have only 4774 unique rows. Any ideas why 53 are missing? Does the isin method has a threshold/limitations? I have double and triple checked the experimentlist, it does have 4827 Strings, and also the other 53 strings do exist in the database as I can query them with cqlsh. Any help much appreciated!

```
Dataset<Row> df1 = sp.read().format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
                .options(new HashMap<String, String>() {
                    {
                        put("keyspace", "mdb");
                        put("table", "experiment");
                    }
                })
                .load().select(col("experimentid")).filter(col("experimentid").isin(experimentlist.toArray()));
List<String> tmplist=df1.distinct().as(Encoders.STRING()).collectAsList();
   
System.out.println("tmplist "+tmplist.size());
```

Comment: is `experimentid` partition key?

Comment: yes! Is there a limitation regarding the partition key?

Comment: No, I would suggest more effective solution :-) Give me some time, to write about it...

Comment: Thank you so much! I look forward for your answer! :)

Comment: forgot to ask - how many nodes is in the cluster, and what is the replication factor for `mdb` keyspace?

Comment: I have 16 nodes in my cluster and a replication factor of 3.
Through my application I have 
        .config("spark.driver.memory","10g")
        .config("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "10g")
        .config("spark.executor.memory","7g")
and in the spark-env file I have:
export SPARK_WORKER_CORES=1
export SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=14000mb 
export SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES=1

Comment: Also I have .config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions",48) and every node/instance has 8 VCPUs and 16Gb of Ram.

Comment: @Des0lat0r, always use java specific `isInCollection(values: java.lang.Iterable[_])` for java list

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I will also try it although I am not very optimistic!

Comment: @SomeshwarKale unfortunately nothing changes with isInCollection..error is still there!

Comment: @Des0lat0r, it was just a suggestion and nothing to do with the issue you are facing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the actual question about "missing data" - there could be problems when your cluster has missing writes, and repair isn't done regularly.  Spark Cassandra Connector (SCC) reads data with consistency level `LOCAL_ONE`, and may hit nodes without all data.  You can try to set consistency level to `LOCAL_QUORUM` (via `--conf spark.cassandra.input.consistency.level=LOCAL_QUORUM`), for example, and repeat the experiment, although it's better to make sure that data is repaired.

Another problem that you have is that you're using the `.isin` function - it's translating into a query `SELECT ... FROM table WHERE partition_key IN (list)`.  See the execution plan:

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra._
import org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra._
scala> val data = spark.read.cassandraFormat("m1", "test").load()
data: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, m: map<int,string>]

scala> data.filter($"id".isin(Seq(1,2,3,4):_*)).explain
== Physical Plan ==
*Scan org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSourceRelation [id#169,m#170] PushedFilters: [*In(id, [1,2,3,4])], ReadSchema: struct<id:int,m:map<int,string>>
```

This query is very inefficient, and put an additional load to the node that performs query.  In the SCC 2.5.0, there are some optimizations around that, but it's better to use so-called "Direct Join" that was also [introduced in the SCC 2.5.0](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2020/05/advanced-apache-cassandra-analytics-now-open-all), so SCC will perform requests to specific partition keys in parallel - that's more effective and put the less load to the nodes. You can use it as following (the only difference that I have it as "DSE Direct Join", while in OSS SCC it's printed as "Cassandra Direct Join"):

```
scala> val toJoin = Seq(1,2,3,4).toDF("id")
toJoin: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int]

scala> val joined = toJoin.join(data, data("id") === toJoin("id"))
joined: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, id: int ... 1 more field]

scala> joined.explain
== Physical Plan ==
DSE Direct Join [id = id#189] test.m1 - Reading (id, m) Pushed {}
+- LocalTableScan [id#189]
```

This direct join optimization needs to be explicitly enabled as [described in the documentation](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/b2.5/doc/14_data_frames.md#special-cassandra-catalyst-rules-since-scc-25).

Comment: Infinite thanks for your answer! I will try to update my SCC but I am not sure that it gives me the choice of .directJoin or .joinWithCassandraTable, the only thing I take is .join and .joinWith. I will update my code with SCC 2.5.0, I will check it and let you know! Hope it is kind of straight forward.

Comment: direct join is the internal implementation - you just doing the normal `.join` on Dataframe, and SCC optimizes it. I've updated answer on how to enable this optimization

Comment: Thank you very much! Will do so. I will just update my code a bit(from SCC 2.4.0 to SCC 2.5.0) and give it a try!

Comment: So, I added the maven dependency of [SCC 2.5.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.spark/spark-cassandra-connector_2.11/2.5.0) to my application and it cannot download it. I downloaded it manually and put it in my repository but still I cannot build my project!

Comment: I just get "Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/datastax/spark/spark-cassandra-connector_2.11/2.5.0/spark-cassandra-connector_2.11-2.5.0.pom" BUILD FAILURE. It doesn't say anything else. It cannot be downloaded, as if the dependency does not exist. In the meantime I used join with the SCC I have(2.4.0). It takes 45mins with the 2 billion rows. However during PCA I get "requirement failed: RowMatrix.computeCovariance called on matrix with only 1 rows. Cannot compute the covariance of a RowMatrix with <= 1 row". It is weird, because if I try it with less data it works fine!!

Comment: What maven coordinates are you exactly using?

Comment: here is the working project: https://github.com/alexott/dse-playground/tree/master/scc-2.5